# Automatic tracking of monitors in Health.app?

Tags: health.app, health-kit

Unless I am mistaken, HealthKit/Health.app will automatically track some BlueTooth sensors, like heart rate straps? Is that true?

Is it also true that other sensors do not work this way, and only work when a 3rd party app is running. Is that also true?

If so, is there a list of such "auto track" devices?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "auto-track" devices per se. You have to go in and give certain apps or devices access to the Health data.

[As detailed on Apple's website,](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203037) you need to choose the fitness app or accessory you want to use, and this will connect it to your Health app.

When you connect apps as a source of data to your Health app, they should automatically push in the data, but you might have to open the app for it to trigger. On the other hand, there are many, many devices that support automatic synchronization, like the Garmin Forerunner 220.

**Unfortunately there are too many devices supporting synchronization with an iOS device, but most apps or devices that are capable of synching with the Health app support auto-synchronization when in close proximity to the device.**

You can see a list of HealthKit compatible devices here: http://www.applehealthkit.com/compatible-devices-apps/.

Comment: So in the Forerunner, you don't have to "do anything" to start tracking? Simply getting close enough so there's data begins the recording process? If so, that seems like close enough to what I want.

Comment: You are almost correct! You do a run, walk, bike on the Forerunner, and when you are close enough to your iPhone (with Bluetooth on), it will automatically sync. You should also check out Motion and Fitness tracking natively supported on iPhone 6/6+/6s/6s+. If you have one, tap Settings > Privacy > Motion and Fitness Tracking to enable it.

Comment: Ok that is just what I was looking for.